# Get all values from column and put them into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get all the values from a column (except header value of course), then populate an array with the column values.  I am restricted to native JavaScript.

This is a table header:

```
<table id="results" width="360" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Date Created</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Tests</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

And this is how the rows are created:

```
      var table = document.getElementById("results");
      var name = document.getElementById("tbName").value;
      var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("select")
      var testArray = [];
      var test;
      for(var i=0; i < elements.length ; i++)
      {
        testArray[i] = elements[i].value;
      }
      test = testArray.join(',');

      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

      if(dd<10) {
          dd='0'+dd
      } 

      if(mm<10) {
          mm='0'+mm
      } 

      today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

      //In the first step using InsertRow function you are creating a first row i.e tr 
      var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

      //In the second step you create a cell i.e td dynamically
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

      // Here in step 3 you can add data to your cells from the modal popup inputs(According to your logic)
      cell1.innerHTML = today;
      cell2.innerHTML = name;
      cell3.innerHTML = test;
```

Again I would like to populate an array with the values in the column `Name`.

Comment: Why dont you store them on creation? Or are they changed by usef?

Comment: @Jonasw Yes they are. The are added dynamically. User fills in form, clicks the button and new row is added to table... So on the creation table rows are empty...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There you go. I think the code is so descriptive it doesn't need further explanation :)

```
var firstCells = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)');
var cellValues = [];
firstCells.forEach(function(singleCell) {
  cellValues.push(singleCell.innerText);
});
console.log(cellValues);
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll will look for td in all tables as per your code. The best way is to make it more specific. for eg: var table = document.getElementById('table'); table.querySelectorAll('td:first-child');

Comment: @KrzysztofZbiciński Thanks for posting this... It is working, kind of, because it takes first child and I need second one... :)

Comment: Then use `td:nth-child(2)`. I've updated the answer. :) @nemo_87

Answer (score 0):

```
 //get parent element
 parent=document.getElementById("name");
//get all tags inside this element
 childs=parent.getElementsByTagName("td or sth like that");
//create an empty array
names=[];
//loop through childs
childs.forEach(child){
     //add child balue to array
     names.push(child.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var table = document.getElementById("result"); //ur table id
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var output = [];
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
{
output.push(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML);//instead of 1 pass column index
}
alert(output);
```